# ht access mod_rewrite query string append flag

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using these two lines in my htaccess to direct `/something` to `/page.php?page=something`. I'd like `/something?key=value` to translate to `/page.php?page=something&key=value`.

These lines do not seem to be working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /$1 [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: Try adding a `RewriteBase /` after the `RewriteEngine on`. If it does not work, what url did you try and what was the result?

Comment: Is it just the QSA that is not working, or is `/something` also not working?

Comment: @ulrich-palha @gerben Thanks for your replies. It is just the QSA that is not working. I've added `RewriteBase /` but no joy. I am essentially going to the URL above `/something?key=value` which for testing purposes is just a page that echos `$_REQUEST['value']. If I go to something.php?key=value then the request parameter is populated with `value`. If I go to the written URL the request param is empty.

Comment: I think you meant `$_REQUEST['value']`. This is a very weird problem. My last (futile) attempt; try using page.php, instead of /page.php?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I am using $_REQUEST['key']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. It actually wasn't working because of another rule in the htaccess file which wasn't written correctly. The code above works fine. Thanks.